# How do I copy selected faces on a rigged character to a new file?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to copy to another file selected faces from a mesh.

This has always been a pain and I assume that this is the the only way to do it.

You CTRL-C the selected object that has the faces you want to move, open a new file, hit CTRL-V, then start removing everything it took with it, such as the skeleton, the unwanted parts of the object, etc.

Is there a way to just copy faces and paste them on a new file?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into Edit mode, select the faces you want to separate
2. Duplicate the faces, separate them into new object with <kbd>P</kbd>
3. In Object mode select object with the separated faces. Rename it accordingly
4. Save your file
5. In a new file execute *Append from file*, choose the renamed object from the file you saved before

Comment: No it's not! What does "Separate the faces" mean? If only there was a properly written explanation.